# Is there a way to let user add and remove fields with Contact Form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I'm building a form with Contact Form 7 and I would need to add multiple fields under a single label and I would need to let the user to add more fields under that same label if needed. I'm using 4 fields as a starting point and I'd like to have like a + sign next to the last field which would add another field to the same set. Example:

```
Prizes:
    [         ]
    [         ]
    [         ]
    [         ] +
```

When that + sign is clicked another field would appear as 5th field

Answer (score 0):

If you know enough about php, jquery and css, you can use [shortcode in contactform 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-shortcode-enabler/), this plugin bring ability to integrate a shortcode inside your contact form, then you can write that shortcode with any functionality you like.

I recommend to add a filter in your shortcode and then by using [metabox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) make your desired field and finally add the shortcode to your contact form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Smart Grid Layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which has a table input construct, allowing you to define the initial fields in a row of a table and then your users can add several rows of these fields, the submission is an array of values for each field.